VSCode MSTest and custom file
Unlike VS 2022, I am struggling to understand a couple of things, but first I share with you my solution:

and this is my test code
        [TestMethod]
        [DeploymentItem("mybibl.json")]
        public void TestJsonReading()
        {
            var jsonmgr = new JsonManager("mybibl");
            var data = jsonmgr.Load();

            Assert.IsNotNull(data);
            Assert.IsTrue(data.Length != 0);
        }

while this is the tested function
public string Load()
{
    string currentPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(currentPath + "\\assets\\" + this._filename))
    {
        return reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

So, I do not understand:

how can I deploy my files that I need for my test functions;
or how can I take the root of the solution to parse the original file in the assets directory

